# Set Text for Custom UIBarButtonItem

Tags: iphone, uibarbuttonitem

I need to set title for Custom UIBarButtonItem.

I've the following code:

```
UIButton* backToRecent = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[backToRecent setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[backToRecent addTarget:self action:@selector(backToRecent) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[backToRecent setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 30)];

UIBarButtonItem* backButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:backToRecent];
[backButtonItem setTitle:@"Recent"];
partViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButtonItem;
[backButtonItem release];
```

But the button appears without the "Recent" text.

Comment: try with this one: partViewController.navigationItem. leftBarButtonItem.title = @"Recent";

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you should set title on the UIButton , not the UIBarButtonItem

```
[backToRecent setTitle:@"Recent" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

and it's not good to make the same name of variable and method

```
[backToRecent addTarget:self action:@selector(backToRecent) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

it's not work , because you use

```
[backToRecent setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

try use

```
[backToRecent setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 18):

Muhammad, I suspect you have resolved this already, but here is an easy way.  Hope this helps someone who is struggling with the same issue:

```
    UIBarButtonItem * backButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Recent" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(backToRecent)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButtonItem;
```